# What exception to raise for python function arguments

Tags: python, exception

I'm creating a function right now that takes in two lists. I want these two lists to be of equal size. I'm trying to figure out what kind of exception I should throw (or If I should throw an exception at all) if they aren't the same size. I kind of want to say ValueError but this is a check that doesn't actually pertain to any single value.

For clarities sake, here's my function stub.

```
def create_form(field_types, field_discriptions):
    pass
```

Comment: ValueError seems good. `string.maketrans` (`str.maketrans` in Python 3.x) raises `ValueError` unless two arguments have same length.

Comment: I think in this case assert is the better choice because I'm making an innate assumption about the values being passed to the function. I think in my particular case I want to reserve ValueError for if someone passes me a wrong field type.

Comment: Raise `TypeError` if wrong field type passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use `assert` and raise an `AssertionError`:

```
assert len(field_types) == len(field_descriptions), "Helpful message"
```

Otherwise, `ValueError` with a message seems like the best choice.

Comment: I can't believe I forgot about asserts. This feels like the right answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own subclass of exception called ArraysNotEqualSizeException.  Might be a bit overkill, but it gets the point across.

Answer (score 1):

throw an exception as the first thing in the function. A function-critical error should not do *anything* without making sure it can do what it wants or it could have bad effects

This isn't a giant error; you should use an assert

> Places to consider putting assertions:
>
> checking parameter types, classes, or values 
>   checking data structure invariants 
>   checking "can't happen" situations (duplicates in a list, contradictory state variables.)
>   after calling a function, to make sure that its return is reasonable
>   -[Python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingAssertionsEffectively)

```
assert len(listone) == len(listtwo), 
    "the function cannot continue because\
     the two arguments passed are of invalid length"
```

a [`ValueError`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html) as suggested by Blender *would* be the right type if you want to use a generic exception, however that's usually reserved for larger issues and would be less helpful.

for quick reference:

> "ValueError
>
> Raised when a built-in operation or function receives an argument that
>   has the right type but an inappropriate value, and the situation is
>   not described by a more precise exception such as IndexError." -[Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html)